# How to make UITableView Recoqnize the category you make?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, categories

I make this simple program:

```
-(void) vPrintAllSubviews
{
    [self printAllSubviewsWithDepth:0];
    while (false);
}

-(void) printAllSubviewsWithDepth:(NSUInteger) depth
{
    UIView * theView= self;
    [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:depth withString: @"abc" startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString * result =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[@"" stringByPaddingToLength:depth withString: @" " startingAtIndex:0], theView];
    PO(result);
    NSArray * subViews = self.subviews;

    for (UIView * subView in subViews) {
        [subView printAllSubviewsWithDepth:depth +1];
    }
}
```

When I call that I got:

```
-[UITableView vPrintAllSubviews]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1faa8c00
```

But UITableView is a subclass of UIView and that category works for all UIView. In fact, the category used to work fine in previous far more complicated project.

So, why UITableView doesn't know that it can access vPrintAllSubviews?

It doesn't even contain any compile error.

If I look at build phases I saw this picture suggesting that only 3 files are being compiled. Hmm... In my last project I do not remember ever need to add .m files to compile lists.

[image]

Comment: are you sure, you imported it and it is available for uiview?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it's the autocomplete that helps me type the selector.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The implementation isn't in the header, importing them is not relevant. I suspect it's rather the `-ObjC -load_all` linker flags that are missing.

Comment: Hmm... Where to add that? I saw that only 3 files are compiled.

Comment: I have used and created 100's of categories but never found this kind of problem. As he says...in the same project able to use for UIView but for subclass it is not working. Strange for me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include your implementation files to the build target.

Probably you copied the resources from another project and you forgot to check the checkmark `Add to Target` in the import dialog.

Comment: I did. Oh I should add the target? Okay.

Comment: the files you see in the `Compile Sources` of your target are the only one which are being linked. If you don't have your category there, it won't be available at runtime.